# Unable to edit list item

Tags: error, list-item, item

I have recently, and for reasons unknown, started to get errors with a particular list on Sharepoint 2013. I am unable to edit existing list items, and attempting to do so throws me to the "Sorry, something went wrong"-screen.

ULS logs gives me some error messages, but I do not know where to go from there:

```
Application error when access /contacts/1/Lists/Contacts/EditForm.aspx, Error=Kan ikke fullføre handlingen.  Prøv på nytt.   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName, String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingPrevCallback, ISPDataCallback pFilterLinkCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback, ISPDataCallback pRowCountCallback, Boolean& pbMaximalView)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName, String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingPrevCallback, ISPDataCallback pFilterLinkCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback, ISPDataCallback pRowCountCallback, Boolean& pbMaximalView)
```

Which translates to: Can not complete the action. Please try again.

and later in ULS log:

```
Failed to get document content data. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Cannot complete this function     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.GetDocumentContentRow(Int32 rowOrd, Object ospFileStmMgr, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& dbres)
```

and "Could not get DocumentContent row: 0x80004005." which I suspect is where the problem lies.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Update**:

I have tried to save the list template (saving it seems to work), however when I try to create a new list based on that template I get thrown to the "Sorry, something went wrong" screen. Creating new lists based on other list templates works just fine, so it seems the problem only applies to one specific list.

ULS logs gives me:

```
Failed to do column assignments for list "Kontaktliste0206" for web "http://intranett/contacts/1", Feature {00BFEA71-7E6D-4186-9BA8-C047AC750105}, Template Id 105.
```

followed by:

```
Failed to create list "Kontaktliste0206" in web "http://intranett/contacts/1", HRESULT=0xdd21ae90. List XML: "<List Name="{CB6DC6C0-5DD3-49D4-80DD-177985CABD72}" Title="Kontakter" Description="Bruk kontaktlisten til å finne informasjon om personer som gruppen arbeider sammen med." Direction="0" BaseType="0" FeatureId="{00BFEA71-7E6D-4186-9BA8-C047AC750105}" ServerTemplate="105" Url="Lists/Contacts" FolderCreation="FALSE" EnableContentTypes="TRUE" NavigateForFormsPages="TRUE" BrowserFileHandling="permissive" Version="83"/>"
```

I am pretty sure I have seen the "Failed to do column assignments" error before, when I try to create/edit a list item.

Also I have been searching around and found that most people experiencing this type of problem have a conflicting value in either the ColName, ID or Name fields. (For instance: [failed-to-do-column-assignments-for-list](http://gordonduthie.net/2011/03/24/failed-to-do-column-assignments-for-list/)). I have looked through the schema and I have no such conflicting values - all those fields are unique.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out a while back, and for those who are experiencing similar issues might want to check out the fields in the list. For me, somehow a field schema had been corrupted and I needed to delete the field and create it again. To find out what field was causing the problem, I created a view and included all the fields available to me. The view did not render (as expected), so from there I only had to deselect fields until I found the culprit.

After finding the broken field I deleted it, and created it once more.

Answer (score 1):

start host services of SharePoint web Application server. Start menu + Run --> services.msc see for some sharepoint host service and start it put it autometic.

Comment: Sorry, this did not work. If this was the problem, wouldnt I have the same problems on all my lists? I only have problem with the one.

Answer (score 1):

Can you open the list in sharepoint designer and create a new edit form and see if it works?